# onAttach() or onActivityCreated(), which is the best place to read activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have fragments created that depends on few properties of its parent activity. I went through  the [Fragment Life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) documents. I need to store the copy of activity in a variable so that I can access it later. There are two place, I could do this

- [onAttach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.app.Activity%29)()
- [onActivityCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Which is the best place that would be recommended and why? There has been instances that [getActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) return null in the fragment after [onAttach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.app.Activity%29)() is called

Comment: onActivityCreated is the first place from where activity is available onAttach comes after that so it doesn't make much difference but I suggest to do that in onActivityCreated.

Comment: If you see the life cycle of fragment, onAttach is called before onActivityCreated

Answer (score 1):

If getActivity() returned null after onAttach() was called, it would only have meant that the fragment was *no longer* attached to activity. So the safest place is still onAttach().

Answer (score 1):

In recent days, I am researching the fragment. the fragment life cycle is described as following:
onAttach()--onCreate()---onCreateView()--onViewCreate()--onActiviyCreate();
then I look up the source code:

```
 @CallSuper
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    mCalled = true;
    final Activity hostActivity = mHost == null ? null : mHost.getActivity();
    if (hostActivity != null) {
        mCalled = false;
        onAttach(hostActivity);
    }
}
@Deprecated
@CallSuper
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    mCalled = true;
}
```

we found the onAttach() checks if the hostActivity has existed, but it can not make sure the activity exists. onActivityCreate() is called when fragment's activity has been created, and tells the fragment that is fully associated with the new activity instance. in other words, activity has completed its own Activity.onCreate().

so I suggest you do it on onActivityCreate() method.